# Invalid Bundle structure The binary file "WatchKitSupport/WK" is not permited

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit

I'm trying to validate my App for iTunesStore, 
My App have Watchkit extention. 
 I archive then validate I get these messages:

```
 ITunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'WatchKitSupport/WK' is not permited. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem. 

Apple Store says that Please Note: Apps built with Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 SDK may be submitted to the App Store. However, WatchKit extensions are not accepted at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including some executable files in your app that shouldn't be there.

For more info: http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2015/03/15/invalid-bundle-structure/